# what are the risks of using apt-get on centos?

Tags: centos, apt-get

I just installed Centos on and installed apt-get on it.
**what are the risk factor of using apt-get on centos..**
I do know that apt-get is for ubuntu, debian.. but since I come from ubuntu background i felt like 'why not'

anyone can clarify if it is usable or just a bad idea and why?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any risk if "apt" is supported by CentOS. But anyway it's better to use native package manager.

Comment: thanks.. i don't understand people who just downvote with no reason .. but i was kinda hoping a more detailed answer..

Comment: I never used CentOS, i just think that  even if  "apt" is supported by CentOS (maybe it's not supported fully ),  there is more chance to meet bugs, this i don't know, but i am sure that the native package manager is fully supported and there is less chance to have problems.
I never try to do the same so i can't be sure.